# Zipping a list and a vector together without repeated traversals

Tags: list, haskell, vector

Say I have a list and a vector, and I want to zip them together. A simple solution is to convert the vector to list, and zip both lists together. But, this requires two traversals for the vector (and also, memory allocation to convert it to list) - one to convert the the vector into list, and another to zip it together with another list.

Is there a way to zip both together in one traversal? I guess this will require some kind of state keeping for zipper (I guess it will keep state for vector index since it can be indexed in O(1) time).

Pseudo-code:

```
let l1 = [1..10] :: [CInt]
let v1 = Data.Vector.Storable.fromList l1

map (\(x,y) -> x + y) (zipListVector l1 v1) -- zipListVector function is what I am after
```

Comment: “A simple solution is to convert the vector to list, and zip both lists together.” Don't they fuse, resulting in a single traversal of the vector?

Comment: @dave4420, good question. I don't know. If the fusion kicks in (even though data type is changing from vector to list - not sure there is a fusion rule for that transformation), I can just use the simple solution instead.

Comment: `Data.Vector.Storable.toList` inlines to something that has a rewrite rule, and `zipWith` has a rewrite rule, but I didn't look closely enough to see whether those rewrite rules work together to result in fusion. It seems plausible to my (relatively inexperienced) mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fusion does kick in here.

Given the following program:

```
import Data.Vector
import Prelude hiding (zip)

zipMe :: [a] -> Vector b -> Vector (a, b)
zipMe xs ys = zip (fromList xs) ys
```

the following Core is generated:

```
Foo.$wzipMe
  :: forall a_auS b_auT.
[a_auS]
-> GHC.Prim.Int#
-> GHC.Prim.Int#
-> GHC.Prim.Array# b_auT
-> Data.Vector.Vector (a_auS, b_auT)
[GblId,
Arity=4,
Str=DmdType LLLL,
Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=4, Value=True,
    ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
    Guidance=IF_ARGS [0 0 0 0] 302 0}]
Foo.$wzipMe =
  \ (@ a_auS)
(@ b_auT)
(w_sW7 :: [a_auS])
(ww_sWa :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
(ww1_sWb :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
(ww2_sWc :: GHC.Prim.Array# b_auT) ->
GHC.ST.runSTRep
  @ (Data.Vector.Vector (a_auS, b_auT))
  (\ (@ s_aBU) (s_aBV :: GHC.Prim.State# s_aBU) ->
    case GHC.Prim.newArray#
        @ (a_auS, b_auT)
        @ (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))
        ww1_sWb
        (Data.Vector.Mutable.uninitialised @ (a_auS, b_auT))
        (s_aBV
        `cast` (GHC.Prim.State#
              (Sym (Control.Monad.Primitive.TFCo:R:PrimStateST <s_aBU>))
            :: GHC.Prim.State# (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)
              ~
            GHC.Prim.State#
              (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))))
    of _ { (# s'#_aSF, arr#_aSG #) ->
    letrec {
      $s$wa_sX0 [Occ=LoopBreaker]
    :: GHC.Prim.Int#
        -> [a_auS]
        -> GHC.Prim.Int#
        -> GHC.Prim.State# (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)
        -> (# GHC.Prim.State# s_aBU, GHC.Types.Int #)
      [LclId, Arity=4, Str=DmdType LLLL]
      $s$wa_sX0 =
    \ (sc_sWB :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
      (sc1_sWC :: [a_auS])
      (sc2_sWD :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
      (sc3_sWE
          :: GHC.Prim.State#
          (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)) ->
      case sc1_sWC of _ {
        [] -> (# sc3_sWE, GHC.Types.I# sc_sWB #);
        : x_aGx xs1_aGy ->
          case GHC.Prim.indexArray#
              @ b_auT ww2_sWc (GHC.Prim.+# ww_sWa sc2_sWD)
          of _ { (# x1_sWp #) ->
          case GHC.Prim.>=# sc2_sWD ww1_sWb of _ {
        GHC.Types.False ->
          $s$wa_sX0
            (GHC.Prim.+# sc_sWB 1)
            xs1_aGy
            (GHC.Prim.+# sc2_sWD 1)
            ((GHC.Prim.writeArray#
            @ (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))
            @ (a_auS, b_auT)
            arr#_aSG
            sc_sWB
            (x_aGx, x1_sWp)
            (sc3_sWE
              `cast` (GHC.Prim.State#
                    (Sym (Control.Monad.Primitive.TFCo:R:PrimStateST <s_aBU>))
                  :: GHC.Prim.State#
                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)
                      ~
                    GHC.Prim.State#
                      (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU)))))
              `cast` (GHC.Prim.State#
                (Control.Monad.Primitive.TFCo:R:PrimStateST <s_aBU>)
                  :: GHC.Prim.State#
                  (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))
                  ~
                GHC.Prim.State#
                  (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)));
        GHC.Types.True -> (# sc3_sWE, GHC.Types.I# sc_sWB #)
          }
          }
      }; } in
    case $s$wa_sX0
        0
        w_sW7
        0
        (s'#_aSF
        `cast` (GHC.Prim.State#
              (Control.Monad.Primitive.TFCo:R:PrimStateST <s_aBU>)
            :: GHC.Prim.State#
              (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))
              ~
            GHC.Prim.State# (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)))
    of _ { (# new_s1_aDv, r1_aDw #) ->
    case r1_aDw of _ { GHC.Types.I# tpl1_aU1 ->
    case GHC.Prim.unsafeFreezeArray#
        @ (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))
        @ (a_auS, b_auT)
        arr#_aSG
        (new_s1_aDv
        `cast` (GHC.Prim.State#
              (Sym (Control.Monad.Primitive.TFCo:R:PrimStateST <s_aBU>))
            :: GHC.Prim.State# (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)
              ~
            GHC.Prim.State#
              (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))))
    of _ { (# s'#1_aV8, arr'#_aV9 #) ->
    (# s'#1_aV8
    `cast` (GHC.Prim.State#
          (Control.Monad.Primitive.TFCo:R:PrimStateST <s_aBU>)
        :: GHC.Prim.State#
            (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (GHC.ST.ST s_aBU))
            ~
          GHC.Prim.State# (Control.Monad.Primitive.R:PrimStateST s_aBU)),
    Data.Vector.Vector @ (a_auS, b_auT) 0 tpl1_aU1 arr'#_aV9 #)
    }
    }
    }
    })
```

which does only one allocation, and fuses those loops.  (I believe it takes advantage of the fact that the length of the zipped vector is at most the length of the initial `Vector`, and allocates a vector that large initially.)

Comment: could you also please explain a bit how you concluded the allocation was done once, from ghc core. This will be very helpful.

Comment: Well, for starters, there was exactly one call to `newArray#`.

Comment: I am still confused. Is there a single traversal here? If the memory is being allocated for the list, the vector must be traversed and copied into the list first, and then zip will traverse it - which is two traversals. You could add to the answer above if you are able to explain that. My ghc core knowledge is still very limited, but I am working on it :)

Comment: The memory is being allocated for the _result._  There is only a single traversal of the input.

Answer (score 1):

GHC does seem to do the clever optimization of traversing the vector once when converting it into the list. Giving credit for answer to @Louis Wasserman, and adding cleared up ghc-core here - my code is different than Louis's - I am zipping into a list instead of a vector (more convenient as list is small, and won't be generated often):

First the code:

```
module Foo where

import Data.Vector
import Prelude

zipMe :: [a] -> Vector b -> [(a,b)]
zipMe xs ys = Prelude.zip xs (toList ys)
```

How to get ghc-core (I used 7.4.1): `ghc -O -fforce-recomp Foo.hs -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`

Cleaned up ghc core output below:

```
--| this is called by zipMeHelper at loop termination
zipMe1 = \ _ -> []

--| Helper function called by zipMe - ys is converted into vector representation (start end array) - that is what I think. Correct me if I got the representation wrong
zipMeHelper =
  \ xs start end array ->
    letrec {
      go =
        \ index ->
          case >=# index end of _ { --| is index >= end? (>=#) is prim version of >=
            False -> --| note vector is being traversed here only once - vector element vecElem is: array at (start + index)
              case indexArray# array (+# start index) of _ { (# vecElem #) ->
              let { --| call a recursive function go2 if end of vector is not reached
                go2 = go (+# index 1) } in
              \ list -> --| take the list element and combine with vecElem
                case list of _ {
                  [] -> [];
                  : x1 xs1 -> : (x1, vecElem) (go2 xs1)
                }
              };
            True -> zipMe1 |-- if here, end of index was reached - terminate with []
          }; } in
    go 0 xs

|-- zipMe function from Foo.hs
zipMe =
  \ xs ys ->
    case ys of _ { Vector start end array ->
    zipMeHelper xs start end array
    }
```